# How to packing and prepare EJB module using multiple jar files?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ejb

I`m trying to create maven (ear) project which will support modularity for ejb beans. I mean that the buissnes objects should be placed in separated jar files. Something like:

```
application.ear
|__ users.jar 
|__ cars.jar
|__ phones.jar
|__ application-ejb.ejb
|__ application-web.war
```

each jar include Entities,Facade and Service which provide data to the war

```
users.jar
|__ User.class (@Entitiy)
|__ UserService.class (@Named, @RequestScoped)
|__ UserFacadeLocal.class (@Stateless, @Local, @PersistenceContext) 

phones.jar
|__ Phone.class (@Entitiy)
|__ PhoneService.class (@Named, @RequestScoped)
|__ PhoneFacadeLocal.class (@Stateless, @Local, @PersistenceContext)

cars.jar
|__ Car.class (@Entitiy)
|__ CarService.class (@Named, @RequestScoped)
|__ CarFacadeLocal.class (@Stateless, @Local, @PersistenceContext)
```

And now my question is how to pack those 3 jar into one ejb during some maven phase? (if it is possible of course and how to do it??) and in the result I will get something like:

```
application-ejb.ejb
|__ User.class (@Entitiy)
|__ UserService.class (@Named, @RequestScoped)
|__ UserFacadeLocal.class (@Stateless, @Local, @PersistenceContext)     
|__ Phone.class (@Entitiy)
|__ PhoneService.class (@Named, @RequestScoped)
|__ PhoneFacadeLocal.class (@Stateless, @Local, @PersistenceContext) 
|__ Car.class (@Entitiy)
|__ CarService.class (@Named, @RequestScoped)
|__ CarFacadeLocal.class (@Stateless, @Local, @PersistenceContext)
```

or there is some different way using just dependency in maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.application</groupId>
        <artifactId>application-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.users</groupId>
        <artifactId>users</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cars</groupId>
        <artifactId>cars</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.phones</groupId>
        <artifactId>phones</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

can someone help me to resolve the issue? I will be grateful for any help

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Why not just add the different jars to your ear with `<type>ejb</type>`?

Comment: why you want to compile 3 jars into one jar .. you can simply put all classes into one project and then compile it ..

Comment: Beacuse application it will be packing depends of requirements. Somethimes it will be needed module for cars and users and sometimes just for cars. I will be Control that using maven profile which will choose needed modules

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the concept of '**Skinny WARs**' by placing these JARs with-in /lib directory of EAR using '*defaultLibBundleDir*' configuration of Maven EAR plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.x</version>
    <configuration>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
```

Check the following article for more details:
[Creating Skinny WARs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html)